# How to fix : "Do not create your own module instances, get them from a ParitcleSystem instance" when trying to loop a ParticleSystem by code

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

I´m trying to start/stop the looping of a particle system by code, and when I did some google search I found that you could do it like this:

```
    [Header("Particles")]
    private ParticleSystem.MainModule particleSystemMain;
    private new ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    public GameObject particles;

    private void Start()
    {
        particleSystem = particles.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        particleSystemMain = particleSystem.main;
    }

    public void ActivateParticles()
    {
        particleSystemMain.loop = true;
    }

    public void ParticlesFalse()
    {
        particleSystemMain.loop = false;
    }`
```

The problem is I am getting this error: `NullReferenceException: Do not create your own module instances, get them from a ParticleSystem instance UnityEngine.ParticleSystem+MainModule.set_loop (System.Boolean value)`

I am doing the looping part wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't change the loop variable in ParticleSystem.MainModule because this is a struct, change this variable directly:

```
[Header("Particles")]
private new ParticleSystem particleSystem;
public GameObject particles;

private void Start()
{
    particleSystem = particles.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
}

public void ActivateParticles()
{
    particleSystem.main.loop = true;
}

public void ParticlesFalse()
{
    particleSystem.main.loop = false;
}
```

Comment: When I do it as in your example this error appears: You can't modify the value of ' ParticleSystem.main' because it´s not a variable

Comment: @AdXxRi, I check this and I think your variable 'particles' or 'particleSystem' is null, I test my own code and this works well

Comment: I will check if its null